# How to call a function inside of a variable inside of another function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

For example:

```
function x() {
    var a = 'Hello';
    var b = y(a); /*how I think it would work*/
    document.getElementById("greet").innerHTML=b;
}

function y(bill) {
    var c = bill+' Billy!';
    return;
}
```

I can't figure it out! I've seen it in code, how I've written it, before but I think that code is beyond outdated. Especially since it was written in like.... 2000 I think? I want it so the variable a would = bill in the function y and then put bill+' billy' thus the output saying. Hello Billy! My actual code is a lot more complex and has a lot going on but this is where everything fudges up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to:

```
function y(bill) {
    var c = bill+' Billy!';
    return c;
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering before me :) and for a correct answer.

Comment: How wow thank you, I missed that derp :P Thank you so much. Is there anything people can give in return on this site? Like a gift or something for contributing? Pts or something?

Comment: Just accept the answer if it is correct or give an up arrow if it is usefull. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do below. return c from y function

```
function x() {
    var a = 'Hello';
    var b = y(a); /*how I think it would work*/
    document.getElementById("greet").innerHTML=b;
}

function y(bill) {
    var c = bill+' Billy!';
    return c; // added
}
```